# Naive Bayes Classifier in Java

Tags: java, naivebayes

Below is a method of mine for classifying fortune cookie messages as either being a predictive message or a wise message.

The database my code builds seems correct, so I'm not worried about that. I built this database on a set of 322 fortune cookie training messages.

The calculation I try to implement below is:

> [(Probability that a message is wise)*(probability that you find
>   "word" knowing the likelihood of finding it in a wise
>   quote)]/(probability of find that word at all)
>
> Done in Log space.

I find that for some reason some probabilities are equal(when they definitely shouldn't be, I've done some hand calculations). TestLabels is a file consisting of the correct answers: either 0's for wise quotes or 1's for predictive ones, all on different lines.

```
 public void classifyOne (Words[] db) throws IOException {

    int right = 0;
    int wrong = 0;
    int equal = 0;
    Scanner inFile1 = new Scanner(new File("testdata.txt"));
    Scanner inFile2 = new Scanner(new File("testlabels.txt"));
    int[] label = new int[101];
    String[] allmessages = new String[101];

    for (int k = 0; k < allmessages.length; k++) {

        String onemessage = inFile1.nextLine();
        allmessages[k] = onemessage;
        String[] wordsfrommsg = onemessage.split("\\s");

        //read in the class of fortune cookie message, either 1 or 0.
        label[k] = Integer.parseInt(inFile2.nextLine());

        //probability based on training data that a quote is either wise or predictive
        double wiseprob = Math.log(170.0)-Math.log(322.0);
        double predictprob = Math.log(152.0)-Math.log(322.0);

        for (int j = 0; j < db.length; j++) {

            for (int i = 0; i < wordsfrommsg.length; i++) {

                //if you find a word in the onemessage that matches a word from the database...
                if (wordsfrommsg[i].equals(db[j].word)) {

                    //multiply by the probability of finding that word, given that it's a prediction quote
                    predictprob += Math.log ((db[j].predcount) / 152.0);
                    //and divide by the probability that I find that word at all.
                    predictprob -= Math.log(((db[j].wisecount + db[j].predcount) / 704.0));
                    wiseprob += Math.log(((db[j].wisecount) / 170.0));
                    wiseprob -= Math.log(((db[j].wisecount + db[j].predcount) / 704.0));
                }
            }
        }

        //there are messages for which the probabilities are equal.
        if(Math.pow(predictprob, 10)==Math.pow(wiseprob, 10)){equal+=1; System.out.println(allmessages[k]);}

        if (Math.pow(predictprob, 10)>Math.pow(wiseprob, 10)) {
            if (label[k] == 1) {
                right++;
            } else {
                wrong++;
            }
        }

        else if (Math.pow(predictprob, 10)<Math.pow(wiseprob, 10)){
            if (label[k] == 1) {
                wrong++;
            } else {
                right++;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println(right);
    System.out.println(wrong);
    System.out.println(equal);
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that comparing words with punctuation to words without punctuation could be the problem?